# How to change a grouping field in a view programmatically?

Tags: 7, views, entities

I've added a custom field to a view and want to display results as a grid grouped by this field. How do I set that "Grouping field Nr.1" option in my code? I tried the following but it doesn't work (probably I'm doing it in the wrong place or change wrong setting...)

```
function MYMODULE_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) 
{
    $view_name = 'MYVIEW';
    $display_name = 'MYDISPLAY';
    if ($view->name == $view_name && $view->current_display == $display_name)
    {
        $custom_field = 'field_MYFIELD_value';

        //code piece adding this field to a view's SELECT statement, sorting by it etc

        $style_options = $view->display['default']->handler->options['style_options'];
        $style_options['grouping'][0]['field'] = $custom_field;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function MYMODULE_views_pre_build( &$view ) {
  $custom_field = 'field_MYFIELD_value';
  $view->display[$view->current_display]->handler->options["style_options"]["grouping"] = $custom_field;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me in Drupal 8 https://www.drupal.org/project/views/issues/1907940

```
function utility_views_pre_view(\Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view, $display_id, array &$args) {
    $view->getStyle()->options['grouping'][0]['field'] = 'field_category';
    }
```